# Find a Div having spaces in its classname HTML DOM

Tags: php, class, html, simple-html-dom

How do I find a div in PHP using HTML DOM which has spaces in its classname.
Snippet

```
<div class="f14 rel">
<input type="checkbox" class="p0m0 mr_5" name="propid[]" id="X6849129" value="X6849129"/>
      <div id="imgChkBoxX6849129">  
          <a id="desc_X6849129" class="f14 uline" target="_blank" href="some link"/>
      </div>
```

I tried `$html->find('div."f14 rel"')`.But it doesn't work.Neither does `$html->find('div.f14 rel')`

Comment: "spaces" in the class name are actually separate class declarations. You should iterate through them and check for the ones you want, etc..

Comment: The classname does not have spaces. You have a div with 2 classnames. My advice would be to give a id and find it that way.

Comment: If you need to match based on two classes you can use `div.f14.rel` that will match a div with both class names.